# How to create List and libraries with CustomSchemaXml property using SchemaXml with CSOM in SharePoint online2010?

Tags: client-object-model

How to create List and libraries with `CustomSchemaXml` property using `SchemaXml` with **CSOM** in sharePoint online2010????

I am using following Code...

```
// Create new list for restore List Item from List Schema XML
 ListCreationInformation listCreationInformation = new ListCreationInformation();
listCreationInformation.Title = "my_List_Name";
listCreationInformation.TemplateType = int.Parse(listServTemplate);
listCreationInformation.Description = listDescription;
listCreationInformation.QuickLaunchOption = QuickLaunchOptions.DefaultValue;
listCreationInformation.CustomSchemaXml = listCustomSchemaXml;//variable to store schemaXML as string reading schema.xml file
ctx.Web.Lists.Add(listCreationInformation);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

It is giving an exception "Invalid list template".

I am using `ClientContext` for user Authentication in **CSOM**.

Answer (score 1):

Did You do some progress in this problem ?
if no, please try:

1. Change **TemplateType** to constant (e.g. 100 as `BaseTemplate`)
2. Exclude **CustomSchemaXml** from your code and rerun program

to detect, which part of your solution is wrong.

My tests with copy lists from source to destination via schema XML strings shows, that `sourcelist.CustomSchemaXml` cannot be applied **as is** during creation of `destinationlist.CustomSchemaXml`. I had to remove many XML elements from source schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out the xml by using Visual Studio. Add a list to a SharePoint project and then grab the schema.xml file.

You also need to provide the featureId of the list template.

I posted a full PowerShell remote provisioning example here: http://www.softlanding.ca/blog/remotely-provision-a-list-using-customschemaxml-(2)

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue on SharePoint 2013. Please check the following when you want to specify custom schema XML:

1. You have to specify correct list template `TemplateType` (like: 100, 101). Here is [enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listtemplatetype).
2. IMPORTANT! You have to specify [template feature ID property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcreationinformation.templatefeatureid.aspx) correctly. See this link, [List of feature ID, listTemplate](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vinitt/archive/2009/11/04/list-of-feature-id-listtemplate.aspx), where are listed all template types and their feature id's.